Runtime error when rendering animation with a frame_change_pre hanlder defined
To visualize time dependent data I make use of handlers. The idea is to change the geometry every time I change the time. A minimal working example is shown here:
def time_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    """
    Function to be called whenever any Blender animation functions are used.
    Updates the geometry according to the function specified.
    """
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    cube = bpy.context.active_object
    cube.location[0] = bpy.context.scene.frame_float/30

# Set the handler function for frame changes (time).
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(time_handler)

# Create a cube.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

While this works as expected when I use the Timeline, rendering the animation results in this error:
Error in bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre[0]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 6, in time_handler
  File "~/bin/blender-4.1.1-linux-x64/4.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Context missing active object

